# Alert for Missing Data on Single Prometheus Metric in Grafana Query

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Prometheus is providing me with some metrics for a queuing service (beanstalkd) via calls to a separate metrics provider (beanstalkd-exporter). A few times a day, I will notice that there is missing data for *some* of the queues.

There are a lot of queues, so I gather them all in a few graphs, queries for which might look like this:

```
tube_current_jobs_ready{tube=~".*some_suffix"}
```

This will get me all the metrics (queues) ending with "some_suffix". One or more of these — but not all — will sometimes have no data, as in a gap in the graph, not zero, but no data at all (presume that the whys and hows of that happening are out of scope for this question).

I already have alerts for when there is no data for the query, and they trigger when all the metrics returned are null, as expected. What I need is an alert for when there is no data for one or more of the metrics returned by the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query for the alert:

```
count_over_time(tube_current_jobs_ready{tube=~".*some_suffix"}[D]) < N
```

This query returns the matching time series where the number of raw samples over the previous duration `D` is less than `N`. Parameters `D` and `N` must be chosen based on the expected interval between raw samples per each time series (aka `scrape_interval` in Prometheus ecosystem). For example, the following query should return time series where the number of samples over the last 5 minutes is less than 4:

```
count_over_time(tube_current_jobs_ready{tube=~".*some_suffix"}[5m]) < 4
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Is it common to have the occasional bad scape? Would saying `5m < 5` instead, make it too noisy?

Comment: This depends on a particular scrape target. Usually scrape targets return responses in less than the specified `scrape_interval`, but some scrape targets may be quite slow.